# RStudio multiline execution doesn't work when lines begin with a comma

Tags: rstudio

It appears that RStudio's multiline execution feature doesn't work when lines begin with a comma. A short example is given below:

```
myData <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), lower = sample(letters, 1000,     replace = TRUE))
library(dplyr)

myMutate <- myData %>% 
  mutate(y = log(abs(x))
         , caps = toupper(lower))
```

When I CTRL+ENTER at the line which begins "myMutate", I receive the following error:

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) :
```

argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Placing the comma on the preceding line runs without any issue.

```
myMutate <- myData %>% 
  mutate(y = log(abs(x)), 
         caps = toupper(lower))
```

I don't see anything about this in the RStudio documentation. Although I understand that beginning a line with a comma may not be everyone's preference, it should be syntactically correct.

Has anyone else run into this?

FWIW, I'm running RStudio 1.0.44 on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: So I finally actually tested your problem. I didn't have R on the computer I wrote the answer from previously and it was slightly misguided because I thought you were having a different issue. That is my mistake. With that said your code works fine on my computer. The version of RStudio you're running isn't as important as the version of R and dplyr that you're using. You might want to post those since it works fine on my system.

Comment: I was able to replicate this; however, the issue appears to be resolved in the current daily build: https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ (tested with RStudio v1.0.106 on macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the current daily build from RStudio (version 1.0.106, Ubuntu desktop 64-bit) resolves this issue. Thanks Kevin Ushey!